# Showing fragment on top of full screen dialog(alertDialog )

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

i have an full screen transparent alert dialog which shows some icon at center bottom having height & width as match_parent,now i need to show a fragment on top of this alert dialog.

I have tried below things:

- Created another alert dialog which works but have to do with android normal fragment
- Tried setting translation z , elvation to fragment container but no luck
- Tried below code but not working

  ```
       View view = findViewById(R.id.frag_container);
       ((View)view.getParent()).requestLayout();
       view.bringToFront();
       view.invalidate();
  ```

Now question is

1. it is achievable
2. if yes then how folkssss?

Comment: can you add screen shot what you want to achieve ... both image without fragment and with fragment

Comment: two alert dialog showing one above another is not possible. But if you explain problem in screen shot then it may be achieved with slight different approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :

```
public class DialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            toast.makeText(this,"enter a text here",Toast.LENTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      })
      .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            finish();
         });
         // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
         return builder.create();
      }
   }
}
```

follow this link for more details - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_alert_dialoges.htm